# No sound on headphones after 14.04 -> 16.04 update

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, headphones

This is related to [No sound after 14.10 -> 15.04 -> 15.10 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/692844/no-sound-after-14-10-15-04-15-10-upgrade)

After the upgrade, there is no sound over the headphones. I can use the same solution in the linked question (in pavucontrol, select "Analog Stereo Output (unplugged)", I also need to select "Headphones (unplugged)" in the "Output Devices" tab, because by default it's Line in). The problem is every time I lock the screen, when I unlock it I need to do these same steps, since it reverts to "Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output".

Something I noticed is that, if I insert the headphones halfway into the jack, the "Analog Stereo Output" (i.e. plugged) appears in the list, but it disappears after I fully insert it. The headphones are working fine, and this didn't happen in 14.04. So, my question is how to either:

- Fix this; or
- Disable jack detection (I only listen using the headphones); or
- Force the selection of "Analog Stereo Output (unplugged)"

  ```
      $ aplay -l
  **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
  card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: VT1705 Analog [VT1705 Analog]
    Subdevices: 0/1
    Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: VT1705 Digital [VT1705 Digital]
    Subdevices: 1/1
    Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 2: VT1705 Alt Analog [VT1705 Alt Analog]
    Subdevices: 1/1
    Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
    Subdevices: 1/1
    Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  ```

Comment: Small update: I've disabled HDMI audio in the BIOS and now it keeps the Audio Stereo Output selected when unlocking the desktop. I still need to change it everytime I boot, but it's much less annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the exact same problem with my stereo plug not being recognized after I changed something with my audio setup but the audio still being output when I selected it manually.

I found my solution in a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/a/806424/714741): I was using the wrong plug on my board. Switching it from the teal-colored rear speakers to "Line Out" (green) now properly makes pulseaudio detect my device and I don't need to disable HDMI output every time the monitor comes back from standby.